# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (8,) into shape (9,)

Tags: python, machine-learning, project, random-forest, k-means

So I am practicing ML on diet recommendations for diabetes patients with the help of BMI and age and I used a total of 2 datasets and they are `input.csv` and `inputfin.csv`. Then, after separating the dataset into breakfast, lunch, and dinner datas and use k-means to it and then use the random forest to get the output.

So the features in the first dataset are like this:

```
Food_items,
Breakfast,
Lunch,
Dinner,
VegNovVeg,
Calories,
Fats,
Proteins,
Iron,
Calcium,
Sodium,
Potassium,
Carbohydrates,
Fibre,
VitaminD,
Sugars
```

and it has like 90 rows to it.

so the features of the second dataset are that

```
0Calories ,
1Fats (gm),
2Proteins(g),
3Iron(mg),
4Calcium(mg),
5Sodium(mg),
6Potassium(mg),
7Carbohydrates (gm),
8Fibre (gm),
9Vitamin D (mcg),
10Sugars (gm)
```

and it has the same values as of it in the first dataset.

my code is given as

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog
main_win = Tk()


def Diabetes_diet():
    print(" Age : %s Years \n Weight: %s Kg \n Height: %s m \n" % (e1.get(), e3.get(), e4.get()))
    
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
    import tkinter as tk
    
    
    ROOT = tk.Tk()
    
    ROOT.withdraw()
    
    USER_INP = simpledialog.askstring(title="Food Timing",
                                      prompt="Enter 1 for Breakfast, 2 for Lunch and 3 for Dinner")
    
    
    data=pd.read_csv('input.csv')
    
    
    Breakfastdata=data['Breakfast']
    BreakfastdataNumpy=Breakfastdata.to_numpy()
    
    Lunchdata=data['Lunch']
    LunchdataNumpy=Lunchdata.to_numpy()
    
    Dinnerdata=data['Dinner']
    DinnerdataNumpy=Dinnerdata.to_numpy()
    
    Food_itemsdata=data['Food_items']
    breakfastfoodseparated=[]
    Lunchfoodseparated=[]
    Dinnerfoodseparated=[]
    
    breakfastfoodseparatedID=[]
    LunchfoodseparatedID=[]
    DinnerfoodseparatedID=[]
    
    for i in range(len(Breakfastdata)):
      if BreakfastdataNumpy[i]==1:
        breakfastfoodseparated.append(Food_itemsdata[i])
        breakfastfoodseparatedID.append(i)
      if LunchdataNumpy[i]==1:
        Lunchfoodseparated.append(Food_itemsdata[i])
        LunchfoodseparatedID.append(i)
      if DinnerdataNumpy[i]==1:
        Dinnerfoodseparated.append(Food_itemsdata[i])
        DinnerfoodseparatedID.append(i)
        
        
    LunchfoodseparatedIDdata = data.iloc[LunchfoodseparatedID]
    LunchfoodseparatedIDdata = LunchfoodseparatedIDdata.T
    val=list(np.arange(5,16))
    Valapnd=[0]+[4]+val
    LunchfoodseparatedIDdata=LunchfoodseparatedIDdata.iloc[Valapnd]
    LunchfoodseparatedIDdata=LunchfoodseparatedIDdata.T
    
    breakfastfoodseparatedIDdata = data.iloc[breakfastfoodseparatedID]
    breakfastfoodseparatedIDdata=breakfastfoodseparatedIDdata.T
    val=list(np.arange(5,16))
    Valapnd=[0]+[4]+val
    breakfastfoodseparatedIDdata=breakfastfoodseparatedIDdata.iloc[Valapnd]
    breakfastfoodseparatedIDdata=breakfastfoodseparatedIDdata.T
    
    DinnerfoodseparatedIDdata = data.iloc[DinnerfoodseparatedID]
    DinnerfoodseparatedIDdata=DinnerfoodseparatedIDdata.T
    val=list(np.arange(5,16))
    Valapnd=[0]+[4]+val
    DinnerfoodseparatedIDdata=DinnerfoodseparatedIDdata.iloc[Valapnd]
    DinnerfoodseparatedIDdata=DinnerfoodseparatedIDdata.T
    
    age=int(e1.get())
    weight=float(e3.get())
    height=float(e4.get())
    bmi = weight/(height**2) 
    
    for lp in range (0,80,10):
        test_list=np.arange(lp,lp+10)
        for i in test_list: 
            if(i == age):
                print('age is between',str(lp),str(lp+10))
                agecl=round(lp/10)    
   
    print("Your body mass index is: ", bmi)
    if ( bmi < 16):
        print("severely underweight")
        clbmi=4
    elif ( bmi >= 16 and bmi < 18.5):
        print("underweight")
        clbmi=3
    elif ( bmi >= 18.5 and bmi < 25):
        print("Healthy")
        clbmi=2
    elif ( bmi >= 25 and bmi < 30):
        print("overweight")
        clbmi=1
    elif ( bmi >=30):
        print("severely overweight")
        clbmi=0
    
    DinnerfoodseparatedIDdata=DinnerfoodseparatedIDdata.to_numpy()
    LunchfoodseparatedIDdata=LunchfoodseparatedIDdata.to_numpy()
    breakfastfoodseparatedIDdata=breakfastfoodseparatedIDdata.to_numpy()
    ti=(clbmi+agecl)/2
    
    ## K-Means Based  Dinner Food
    Datacalorie=DinnerfoodseparatedIDdata[1:,1:len(DinnerfoodseparatedIDdata)]
    X = np.array(Datacalorie)
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0).fit(X)
    XValu=np.arange(0,len(kmeans.labels_))
    dnrlbl=kmeans.labels_
    
    ## K-Means Based  Lunch Food
    Datacalorie=LunchfoodseparatedIDdata[1:,1:len(LunchfoodseparatedIDdata)]
    X = np.array(Datacalorie)
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0).fit(X)
    XValu=np.arange(0,len(kmeans.labels_))
    lnchlbl=kmeans.labels_
    
    ## K-Means Based  Breakfast Food
    Datacalorie=breakfastfoodseparatedIDdata[1:,1:len(breakfastfoodseparatedIDdata)]
    X = np.array(Datacalorie)
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0).fit(X)
    XValu=np.arange(0,len(kmeans.labels_))
    brklbl=kmeans.labels_
    
    ## Reading of the Dataset
    inp=[]
    datafin=pd.read_csv('inputfin.csv')
    datafin.head(5)
    dataTog=datafin.T

    bmicls=[0,1,2,3,4]
    agecls=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    
    diabetescat = dataTog.iloc[[0,1,2,7,8,10]]
    diabetescat=diabetescat.T

    
    diabetescatDdata=diabetescat.to_numpy()
    
    diabetescat=diabetescatDdata[1:,0:len(diabetescatDdata)]
    
   
    diabetescatfin=np.zeros((len(diabetescat)*5,9),dtype=np.float32)
    t=0
    r=0
    s=0
    yt=[]
    yr=[]
    ys=[]
    for zz in range(5):
        for jj in range(len(diabetescat)):
            valloc=list(diabetescat[jj])
            valloc.append(bmicls[zz])
            valloc.append(agecls[zz])
            diabetescatfin[t]=np.array(valloc)
            yt.append(brklbl[jj])
            t+=1
        for jj in range(len(diabetescat)):
            valloc=list(diabetescat[jj])
            valloc.append(bmicls[zz])
            valloc.append(agecls[zz])
            diabetescatfin[r]=np.array(valloc)
            yr.append(lnchlbl[jj])
            r+=1
        for jj in range(len(diabetescat)):
            valloc=list(diabetescat[jj])
            valloc.append(bmicls[zz])
            valloc.append(agecls[zz])
            diabetescatfin[s]=np.array(valloc)
            ys.append(dnrlbl[jj])
            s+=1
    X_test=np.zeros((len(diabetescat),10),dtype=np.float32)

   
    for jj in range(len(diabetescat)):
        valloc=list(diabetescat[jj])
        valloc.append(agecl)
        valloc.append(clbmi)
        valloc=valloc*ti
        X_test[jj]=np.array(valloc)
    
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    
    val=int(USER_INP)
    
    if val==1:
        X_train= diabetescatfin
        y_train=yt
        
    elif val==2:
        X_train= diabetescatfin
        y_train=yr 
        
    elif val==3:
        X_train= diabetescatfin
        y_train=ys
    
   
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    
    
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
    
    clf=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
    
    clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
    
    y_pred=clf.predict(X_test)
    
    
    
    
    print ('SUGGESTED FOOD ITEMS ::')
    for ii in range(len(y_pred)):
        if y_pred[ii]==2:
            print (Food_itemsdata[ii])    

Label(main_win,text="Age",font='Helvetica 12 bold').grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W,pady=4)
Label(main_win,text="Weight",font='Helvetica 12 bold').grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W,pady=4)
Label(main_win,text="Height", font='Helvetica 12 bold').grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=W,pady=4)

e1 = Entry(main_win,bg="light grey")
e3 = Entry(main_win,bg="light grey")
e4 = Entry(main_win,bg="light grey")
e1.focus_force() 

e1.grid(row=1, column=1)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
e4.grid(row=3, column=1)


Button(main_win,text='Quit',font='Helvetica 8 bold',command=main_win.quit).grid(row=5,column=0,sticky=W,pady=4)
Button(main_win,text='Diabetes Diet',font='Helvetica 8 bold',command=Diabetes_diet).grid(row=3,column=4,sticky=W,pady=4)

main_win.geometry("400x200")
main_win.wm_title("DIET RECOMMENDATION SYSTEM")
main_win.mainloop()
```

the datasets and reference for this code is from the github account
[1st dataset](https://github.com/frason88/Diet-Recommendation-System-/blob/main/input.csv)
[2nd dataset](https://github.com/frason88/Diet-Recommendation-System-/blob/main/inputfin.csv)

So when I typed 1 to get the breakfast as the output after entering the age height weight as input.

I expected to get the output by printing the names of the food items but I am getting an error in it.

the error is

```
Age : 19 Years 
 Weight: 78 Kg 
 Height: 1.82 m 

age is between 10 20
Your body mass index is:  23.54788069073783
Healthy
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:\VS code\test1.py", line 162, in Diabetes_diet
    diabetescatfin[t]=np.array(valloc)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (8,) into shape (9,)
```